# Is $f(x)$ is more curvature than $g(x)$ then length of $f(x)$ seem longer than length of $g(x)$?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis

**In my obsevation:**

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two continuous funcions, and they have [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) and [second derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative) are also continuous in interval $[a, b]$. If $f(x)$ is more **[curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature)** than $g(x)$ in interval $[a, b]$ and $f(a)=g(a)$, $f(b)=g(b)$ then length of $f(x)$ from $a$ to $b$ seem longer than length of $g(x)$ from $a$ to $b$ ?

**Example:** *Length of any curve (curve is not a line) is longer than a line in every interval.*

This observation can fomulate that:

$$\frac{|f''(x)|}{(1+f'(x)^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \ge \frac{|g''(x)|}{(1+g'(x)^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ and $f(a)=g(a)$, $f(b)=g(b)$

then $$\int_{a}^{b}{ \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}}dx \ge \int_{a}^{b}{ \sqrt{1+g'(x)^2}}dx$$

> > **My question:** I think this is true and well-known, can you share me a reference. If this result is not known can you give a proof or a comment? Thank You very much.

Comment: For simplicity, assume that $f'' \ge 0$ and $g'' \ge 0$ to get rid of the modulus, integrate on $[a,b]$ and see what you get. Next try the general case. This should have been asked on [Mathematics], though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no. Indeed, if this conjecture were true, then the conditions $f(a)=g(a)$, $f(b)=g(b)$, and 
\begin{equation}
 k_f(x):=\frac{|f''(x)|}{(1+f'(x)^2)^{3/2}}=k_g(x) 
\end{equation}
for all $x \in [a, b]$ would imply that 
\begin{equation}
 \ell_f:=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\,dx=\ell_g; 
\end{equation}
that is, we would have that the length of the graph of a smooth enough function $f$ over $[a,b]$ would be determined by the curvature of the graph and the values of $f$ at $a,b$.

Let us show that this is not so. Indeed, let 
\begin{equation}
 h(x):=\frac12 \sqrt{\frac{(1+4 x^2)^{3/2}-3 x-8 x^3}{x+3 x^3}}. 
\end{equation}
Everywhere here $x>0$, unless otherwise specified. 
It is not hard to see that the expression under the square root is $>0$, so that the definition of $h$ is correct. 
Let now 
\begin{equation}
 f(x):=\int_a^x h(u)\,du
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
 g(x):=x^2-a^2,
\end{equation}
where $a:=1/100$. 
Then 
\begin{equation}
 \frac{f''(x)}{(1+f'(x)^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{-2}{(1+4x^2)^{3/2}}=-\frac{g''(x)}{(1+g'(x)^2)^{3/2}}. 
\end{equation}
So, the function $f$ is concave, the function $g$ is convex, $f(a)=g(a)$, and 
\begin{equation}
 k_f=k_g. 
\end{equation}
Moreover, $f'(a)>g'(a)$. So, there is a unique real $b>a$ such that $f(b)=g(b)$; in fact, $b=0.710526\ldots\;$. 
However, 
\begin{equation}
 \ell_f=0.920463\ldots\ne0.894858\ldots=\ell_g,
\end{equation}
which does disprove the conjecture.

This counterexample is illustrated here:

[image]

Comment: Your answer is very nice.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: *"we would have that the length of the graph of a smooth enough function $f$ over $[a,b]$ would be determined by the curvature of the graph and the values of $f$ at $a,b$."* But don't we have this? It seems to me that this is an immediate consequence of the fundamental theorem of curves: given the curvature and torsion (in this case $0$), there exists a unique curve possessing them, modulo isometries ([theorem 2.1.7](http://uregina.ca/~mareal/cs2.pdf)). In particular, its length will be unambiguously determined by the curvature function alone.

Comment: @AlexM. I think the point of the example is that we have equality of the two curvatures at points with the same $x$-coordinate, not at points the same distance along the curves.

Comment: @AlexM. : Andreas Blass stated the point of the example exactly right.